# Cannot create new GWT project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I was looking for the solution everywhere but cannot find anything that worked for me.

I've got Eclipse Oxygen and installed GWT plugin (taken from Eclipse Marketplace).
When I'm trying to create new GWT project, afer giving project name and package name and unticking (this is important as with this option ticked, project is creating but stil not working) "Generate project sample code" and clicking Finish I've got error message saying "Creation of element failed. See error log for more details"

In error I have the following error:

Plug-in: org.eclipse.jdt.ui

Message: internal error

error message:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard.performFinish(NewElementWizard.java:136)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.NewWebAppProjectWizard.performFinish(NewWebAppProjectWizard.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.actions.AbstractOpenWizardAction.run(AbstractOpenWizardAction.java:103)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.actions.NewWebAppToolbarHandler.execute(NewWebAppToolbarHandler.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.launch.LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.getShell(LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.java:110)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.launch.LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.generateUrl(LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.java:130)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.launch.WebAppLaunchUtil.determineStartupURL(WebAppLaunchUtil.java:139)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.createLaunchConfig(WebAppProjectCreator.java:558)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.create(WebAppProjectCreator.java:372)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.NewWebAppProjectWizard.finishPage(NewWebAppProjectWizard.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$2.run(NewElementWizard.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5660)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Root exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.launch.LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.getShell(LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.java:110)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.launch.LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.generateUrl(LegacyGWTLaunchShortcutStrategy.java:130)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.launch.WebAppLaunchUtil.determineStartupURL(WebAppLaunchUtil.java:139)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.createLaunchConfig(WebAppProjectCreator.java:558)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.create(WebAppProjectCreator.java:372)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.NewWebAppProjectWizard.finishPage(NewWebAppProjectWizard.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$2.run(NewElementWizard.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5660)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.2.M20171130-0510
java.version=1.8.0_151
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/E:/eclipse-workspace/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Any ideas what is wrong with my eclipse? I tried to re-install but no luck so far

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is a **known issue of the GWT Eclipse Plugin**: [Issue #351 - *Unable to create new project*](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/351).

Unfortunately, it is still opened. As a workaround, you may try to fix issues with generated samples (at least, just remove all code except module with empty entry point). Or use Maven/Gradle as a starting point for the project.

Comment: thanks howlger for you message. Yep I've seen this issue no 351 but was thinking that this problem is rather rare as there are no other hints re this problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Create a project using command line utility webAppCreator as described at http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html. It generates the files to start a GWT project. One should download GWT SDK for this. Apache Ant is also needed to run command line arguments. Please set ANT_HOME environment variable and append Path pointing to the bin directory. Import the project into Eclipse.